# Wait for document to fully open before running macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

Can I make Word wait until a document is fully open and all fields have been populated, before running a macro? I have tried using the `Document_Open()` but unfortunately this runs too early.

I'm trying to unlink all the fields using the macro below. This works on a document that is already open. It errors out because there is no document yet, when used on `Document_Open()`

```
Sub SelectUnlink()
    ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Range.Fields.Unlink
    Selection.End = Selection.Start
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Is `ThisDocument` accessible?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon No, same error

Comment: And what is that error? 91? Something isn't right, `Document_Open` is fired by the `Document` object, which should be `ThisDocument`. Need more info.

Comment: Just add the command to update all fields in your code.  Once that completes you should be good to go.

Comment: Try to put a `DoEvents` after the line that opens the document

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I've added a screenshot off the error to the question.

Comment: Thanks, saw that. If you hit [debug], which instruction is it taking you to?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Takes me to `ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select`

Comment: ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select  There will be no fields in this range to update.  You need ActiveDocument.Content.Fields.Unlink

Comment: I've just now put `ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select` in the `Document_Open` handler of a new macro-enabled document, and everything works smoothly. There's something else involved. In any case if you mean to work with `ThisDocument` (*that* specific document), don't use `ActiveDocument` (whichever document is currently active).

Comment: Is your `Document_Open` handler in `ThisDocument` or in the `Normal` template?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon The macro is in my normal template. The call to the macro is within the `Document_Open` method within the document. I think there may be some interference from the document management system that opens the template but even opening it manually, I get the error.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon It seems like the template is removing the `Document_Open` method when I save it? It's a `.dot` if that matters. Any ideas?

Comment: `.dot` isn't macro-enabled, for one (try `.dotm`). What version are you using? 2016? 2010? 365? Insider build?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon 2013. I know it's not macro enabled but I have read that you can save macro code in .dot templates anyway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192446/discussion-between-syntax-error-and-mathieu-guindon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that whenever it is you're running into this error, it isn't being caused by your Document_Open macro running automatically, as the call to SelectUnlink could not be run before there is an open document. It could happen if you're running your Document_Open or SelectUnlink macro manually, however, when no document is open. That said, in your Document_Open macro, you could replace the call to SelectUnlink with:

```
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
ActiveDocument.Fields.Unlink
```

Answer (score -2):

Just put a Error Treatment .

```
Sub SelectUnlink()
    ON ERROR GOTO FINISH
    ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Range.Fields.Unlink
    Selection.End = Selection.Start
    FINISH:

End Sub
```

Comment: Other than ignoring the error, not attempting to get the desired code outcome, and pretending everything is OK, what is this going to accomplish?